# Not able to connect to AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am getting the below error when trying to connect to RDS SQL Server database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Configuration of AWS is as follows:

I have a vpc which has a public subnet and a private subnet. The private subnet has two ec2 instances and both the ec2 instances has the same security group. I am able to connect to rds instance with one ec2 instance but getting the above error when trying to connect with the second ec2 instance. All the resources have the same availability zone.

I have tried below options but not able to resolve the issue:

I have tried adding the IP address of the ec2 instance in the rds server's security group directly but that is not helping.

I have disabled the firewall and anti-virus but it is not making any difference.

I have telnet from the ec2 instance to the rds server on port 1433 and I am not able to connect. So it looks like the issue is with a firewall or security group.

I have checked Network ACLS but we don't have any specific ACL set up. It just has default rules which are not blocking any traffic.

I have double-checked everything (security group, network ACL, DNS name of the server, credentials) but not able to figure this out. Please help me to get this fixed.

Comment: What's the difference between the two instances?

Comment: Both the instances are the same but they have different applications running on them...

Comment: RDS security group (SG) allows incoming connections from the SG of the instances, or there are some different ingress criteria?

Comment: It's allowing connections from the SG of the instances

Comment: Do the EC2 instances have different IAM Roles?

Comment: What IPs are you adding in RDS security group? Private IPs of EC2? Can you try updating RDS security group with CIDR of private subnet?

Comment: @saurabh14292 I have added the private ip of the EC2. I have also tried adding CIDR of private subnet but it not helping

Comment: @AlwaysLearning both the instances have the same IAM role

Comment: Can you create another batch of identical EC2 instances and try connecting them to RDS? How are you creating those EC2 anyway? Manually or through some IaC tool?

Comment: I have tried adding another ec2 instance but not able to connect from that as well... I am creating the instances manually not using any Iac tool for now

Comment: I have checked vpc, subnet, network ACL, security group, firewall ... anything else I should check?

Comment: I have found that there is a version upgrade available for mssql server and I am able to connect to the mssql server after upgrading

Comment: I am still not sure about what the problem was but I am anyways planning to upgrade the db server so it's not a problem for me. Still if anyone able to find the reason for this, please answer...